# How is ReactiveX different from multithreaded programming

Tags: multithreading, reactivex

Reading about ReaactiveX(like [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html)), it states something like:

```
An advantage of this approach is that when you have a bunch of tasks that are not dependent on each 
other, you can start them all at the same time rather than waiting for each one to finish before 
starting the next one — that way, your entire bundle of tasks only takes as long to complete as the 
longest task in the bundle.
```

Are not we all doing this already using multi threading programming? So how are two things different actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a broader topic about light-weight async tasks in general vs threads.

A big difference is in cost and speed. Threads are expensive, and OSs generally limit the number that you can create. Every thread has room for an entire full stack set aside in case it's needed (you get a StackOverflow if it wasn't enough). If you have more threads than processors, then switching tasks means saving off all the current thread info and loading the new thread into registers, etc.

ReactiveX libraries work with callbacks, so the only memory needed is the object with the callback data. Switching ReactiveX tasks is just a method call.

You can have many millions of ReactiveX tasks in progress at once, not so much with threads.

Most slow tasks (like file or network IO) actually do a lot of waiting. Why allocate an entire thread just to do nothing but wait?

With ReactiveX, the tasks are just simple objects that are waiting, just sitting in a queue.

Now, ReactiveX is built on top of threading. Those millions of tasks (just callback object in memory) when actually running are running on some thread. And ReactiveX, tasks aren't all really "running" at the same time (only a thread running on a core can actually do something). Most tasks do a lot of waiting so really those millions of ReactiveX tasks, are really just all "waiting" at the same time by hanging out in a queue.

Also, consider a scenario like Javascript, which is a single threaded environment. Multi-threading just isn't an option there. Even if you can create threads, avoiding concurrency or simplifying UI code that needs thread affinity can be nice when many tasks are all managed on a single thread.

Even in multiple thread scenarios, ReactiveX can be really helpful since it's API guarantees synchronous event callback for a particular stream, even if that steam is using many threads to generate the data.